# multichoice Matlab for loops

Tags: matlab, for-loop

Can anyone tell me how I would work this out manually?

Consider the following MATLAB function:

```
function Anew = mystery( A ) 

N=5;  
for ii=2:N     
    Anew(ii)= A(ii-1); 
end   
end
```

If we define `v = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`.  What would be the output of `x = mystery(v)` be?

- a) `x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]`
- b) `x = [1 2 3 4 5 6]`
- c) `x = [0 1 2 3 4 5]`
- d) `x = [0 0 1 2 3]`

Comment: Do your homework yourself!

Comment: its not homework, its revision sheets im doing before a test....

Comment: Why don't you try stepping through the code yourself with each input and seeing what the result looks like?.... but if you really must know, this code basically returns an array of 5 elements where the first element is **always** zero, while the other four elements are the first four elements of the array of `A`.

Comment: i tried doing 
0(2-1)=0
1(3-1)=2
2(4-1)=3
3(5-1)=12

but that's obviously not the answer

Comment: look i know the answer is D, i just want to know what the process is

Comment: Read my first comment very carefully.

Comment: Why are you multiplying your outputs?  You are simply doing a copy of elements from one array to another.  No need to multiply anything.

Comment: OK, I'll write you an answer.  Give me a moment.

Comment: Wrote an answer.  That's as verbose as I can get.  Good luck on your test!

Answer (score 2):

OK, let's step through this code line by line.

---

The first line:

```
N = 5;
```

This basically creates a variable called `N` and stores the value of 5 in it.  No biggie.

Next line:

```
for ii = 2 : N
```

This is a `for` loop, and each time the loop iterates, the value of `ii` will change by 1.  The first time the loop runs, `ii = 2`, then the next time it starts again, `ii = 3` up to `ii = 5`, then the loop stops.

So, let's start at the beginning with `ii = 2`.  The statement inside the loop is equivalent to:

```
Anew(2) = A(2-1);
```

This simplifies to:

```
Anew(2) = A(1);
```

If you look at the code, `Anew` was never defined up until this point.  When you try to assign a value to a location in an array that was not previously declared, MATLAB will fill up the values that are before the location of where you assigned to be zero automatically.  As such, if you did:

```
Anew(8) = 9; %// For example
```

`Anew` would look like this:

```
Anew = 

0    0    0    0    0    0    0    9
```

The 8th position has the value of 9, while the other positions before the 8th one are all zero.  Therefore, by doing `Anew(2) = A(1);`, the first position of `Anew` is zero, while the second position of `Anew` gets the first value of `A` and puts it here.  As such, `Anew` currently looks like:

```
Anew = 

0    0
```

Let's do `ii = 3`.  This means that in your loop, the statement simplifies to:

```
Anew(3) = A(3-1);
```

.... which is:

```
Anew(3) = A(2);
```

This means that the third position of `Anew` gets the second element of `A` copied over here.  Note that the original size of `Anew` was 2.  By doing `Anew(3) = A(2);`, MATLAB will automatically adjust the size of `Anew`, and then put what `A(2)` is into the third position of `Anew`.  Therefore, `Anew` looks like:

```
Anew = 

0    0    1
```

As a little test, if we were to do `Anew(6) = A(2);`, this is what it would look like:

```
Anew = 

0    0    0    0    0    1
```

Note that we previously had `Anew = [0 0];` before this point.  By doing `Anew(6) = A(2);`, the 3rd, 4th and 5th positions of `Anew` get filled with 0, and the 6th position gets the value of 1, which is `A(2)`.

You can probably see a pattern now.  Each position of `Anew` gets the element of `A` shifted to the left by 1.  Therefore, for `ii = 4`:

```
Anew(4) = A(3);
```

What it looks like now is:

```
Anew = 

0    0    1    2
```

Finally for `ii = 5`, we get:

```
Anew(5) = A(4);
```

What it looks like now is:

```
Anew = 

0    0    1    2    3
```

After the end of this loop, `Anew` gets returned as the output of `mystery`.

Therefore, the answer is **(d)**: `x = [0 0 1 2 3];`.

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: @user3517701 - My pleasure.  If you like, consider accepting my answer to signify you don't need anymore help.  Click on the checkmark icon just underneath the up and down arrows at the top of my post to the left.